# Synctex don't work with tabularray package

Tags: forward-inverse-search, tabularray

With the tabular environment I can jump to the correct line with inverse search: ctrl click in the pdf output (with Texstudio or Texworks). Why it doesn't work with the tabularray package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    a & b \\
    \hline
    c & d \\
    \hline
    e & f \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}


\begin{tblr}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    a & b \\
    \hline
    c & d \\
    \hline
    e & f \\
    \hline
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `tblr`, like `tabularx` and `amsmath` alignments, grabs the whole environment so it can do multiple trial passes. So tex has always read to the `\end` line and that shows in line numbers if there is an error, and in synctex.

Comment: @user202729 What is the name of your new package? I am very interested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my new package. Currently it's not on CTAN yet, so it's subject to change.

You need to get the source code on https://github.com/user202729/TeXlib and compile the file with LuaLaTeX.

```tex
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{cprotectinside}
\cprotectinsideEnableSyncInner

\begin{document}

\cprotectinside{!}{
\begin{tblr}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    !a! & !b! \\
    \hline
    !c! & !d! \\
    \hline
    !e! & !f! \\
    \hline
\end{tblr}
}

\cprotectinside{!}{
\begin{tblr}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    !a! & !b\hspace{0pt}! \\
    \hline
    !c! & !d\hspace{0pt}! \\
    \hline
    !e! & !f\hspace{0pt}! \\
    \hline
\end{tblr}
}


a%
a%
a
a%
a%
a%

\end{document}
```

Remark:

- as you can see, you need to manually wrap each cell (although this can be somewhat "automated" by using regex etc. to parse the table content)
- you need to add some space for synctex to work properly. The first table doesn't work because there's no space, the second table works even if a zero-width space is added.

  This is an inherent limitation in TeX, as you can see in the last paragraph there are 6 `a`s; however synctex is only accurate on a "word" level (where there are space between), it cannot distinguish between the 3 first `a` or 3 last `a` since there's no "space" between them.

  It appears that `tabular` environments uses "real space" to split the rows so this is not necessary; however for `tabularray` it's necessary because (I assume) it uses a different mechanism to arrange the table.

Comment: +1 Interesting solution. But still a little complicated.

Comment: And can it be used also for `longtblr`?

Comment: @L.J.R. Yes it can be used for everything.

Comment: @L.J.R. If you mean "complicated" by "it needs manual intervention", then as I mentioned in the answer it's possible to pre-parse the table content and inject the delimiter in; nevertheless (as with most things in TeX) tabularray is the only thing that can parse tabularray environment correctly. It's also an option for you to modify your package to conditionally support preserving synctex

Comment: Possibly as a `synctex` library of `tabularray` in the future. But not an emergent thing to do. I assume it is not that easy to make it work well while not interfering existing functionally.